# When is a Facebook PSID created (or does it always exist)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I request a `PSID` from the `ASID` via the `ID Matching API`, will it be guaranteed to exist?

I can't test it with a sandbox account, because obviously my account is linked to the page somehow.

But if a random user were to log in to my Page with Facebook and I try to grab a `PSID` with the `ASID` that I got from that login, will it be guaranteed to exist?

Comment: _“But if a random user were to log in to my Page with Facebook”_ - they would be logging in to your _website_ - not “page” as in Facebook page. PSIDs are only relevant in the latter context, for messaging between a user and a page. Not sure if that even is your scenario here …?

Comment: @04FS If I understood it correctly, they would log into my App, therefore I get tthe ASID. I want to greet the user via Messenger when he logs into my app. Everything works so far on Sandbox, but I am not sure, if I can also make that connection with some random user account.

Comment: You can only message users who messaged your page first.

Comment: @04FS Oh ok thanks for that info. Is there some fast way to make sure the user messeges my app? Like, where you only have to press a button?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery

Comment: @04FS Thank you a lot for your help, this was what i am searching for! I would really like to accept your answer, if you could copy your comment(s) into one real quick?

Answer (score 0):

> But if a random user were to log in to my Page with Facebook

They would be logging in to your website - not “page” as in Facebook page. PSIDs are only relevant in the latter context, for messaging between a user and a page.

You can only message users, who messaged your page first.

To encourage them to do that, there’s several plugins available: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery